# Is there way to limit MKMapView, i.e. to a city?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am developping a  iphone app to localize service around a city. My question is about how is posible to limit the map only to this city. For example,  about controlling the user position?
I mean, if  at start,  app verifies that user is far enough from the city, the app adverts about that. How could control this situation (or there are another way to do that)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.

Check the coordinates and when these gets too far from your point - use this Method

```
- (void)setCenterCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to get him back where you want him.

Comment: tx! There is there a method in order to check the distance or  I write my method to do that?